# Yii2 register mix of JS Files and Inline JS in order

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, yii2

I'm trying to register the following from the [Google Analytics docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/):

```
<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script>
  window.ga=window.ga||function(){(ga.q=ga.q||[]).push(arguments)};ga.l=+new Date;
  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<script async src='https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js'></script>
<!-- End Google Analytics -->
```

So I did the following in my widget:

```
$this->view->registerJs('
    window.ga=window.ga||function(){(ga.q=ga.q||[]).push(arguments)};ga.l=+new Date;
    ga(\'create\', \'UA-XXXXX-Y\', \'auto\');
    ga(\'send\', \'pageview\');
', View::POS_HEAD);

$this->view->registerJsFile(
    'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js',
    [
       'async'=>'async',
       'position' => View::POS_HEAD,
    ]
);
```

But the registered JS File came out BEFORE the Inline JS. Is there a way to get the scripts to respect the order?

I thought about using an AssetBundle and the 'depends' protocol, but there's nothing in the Yii2 Docs about Inline JS in an AssetBundle.

You can give the Inline JS a key, but sadly the 'depends' protocol requires a class name.

Comment: Does the position matter in this particular case of Analytics implementation (async)? Just asking.

Comment: @Ravenous That's a good question! I don't know.. I guess I'll just leave it if it doesn't.. but it irks me greatly :)

Comment: It shouldn't really matter. I mean logically, the browser does not know what "window.ga" is until the script that follows gets loaded.

Comment: If you really want, you could just bypass AssetBundle for this particular scenario and embed the scripts manually after `head()` of `yii\web\View` takes place or create an actual file instead of an inline script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the only easy way to do this is by not using AssetBundle in this particular case and manually embed the code in your partial/layout file, after`<?php $this->head() ?>`

Comment: Ended up doing this after wrapping the code up in widgets, I think I actually prefer it to registering the scripts.

Answer (score 2):

You can move the first code block to a js file and use it in an asset bundle. Then for the second js url use that asset as dependancy

google_analytics.js

```
window.ga=window.ga||function(){(ga.q=ga.q||[]).push(arguments)};ga.l=+new Date;
 ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
 ga('send', 'pageview');
```

GoogleAnalyticsAsset.php

```
<?php

namespace app\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class GoogleAnalyticsAsset extends AssetBundle
{
   public $basePath = '@webroot/web';
   public $baseUrl = '@web/web';

   public $jsOptions = ['position' => \yii\web\View::POS_HEAD];
   public $css = [
   ];
   public $js = [
       'js/google_analytics.js',
   ];
   public $depends = [
   ];
}
```

Inside your widget

```
use app\assets\GoogleAnalyticsAsset;
public function init() {
    GoogleAnalyticsAsset::register( $this->getView() );
    parent::init();
}

public function run()
{
   $this->registerJsFile('https://www.google.com/jsapi',['position' => \yii\web\View::POS_HEAD,'depends' => 'app\assets\GoogleAnalyticsAsset']);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that does look a bit overkill though.. and it makes it a lot harder for the team to find in the codebase.

Comment: Yes its a workaround. Your code is enough for it to work.Weird that it doesn't.

Comment: It's because the JS Files and Inline JS go into separate arrays.. and then when they are rendered the Files array gets rendered first.